# System configration data updated error

Tags: boot

I have Rack Express5800/R120a-2 server, after POST this error appeared:

System Configuration Data updated ERROR

System Configuration Data read ERROR

Press F1 to resume.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Start by pressing F1.

Comment: Is there another solution??